# Error importing JSON into SQL-Database with pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, json, sql-server, import

I am trying to import json-data from an API to an SQL-Database with Python and pyodbc.

Example JSON-Data

```
 "id": "unique id string",
 "created_at": "NULL",
 "creator_id": "creator_id",
 "updated_at": "NULL",
 "updater_id": "updater_id",
 "name": "Name",
```

SQL-Table
[SQL-Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnNNd.png)

Insert-function (SQL Connection works properly I am sure of that):

```
data_string = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO SQLTable VALUES (?)", data_string)
```

Error I get:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('21S01', '[21S01] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition. 
(213) (SQLExecDirectW); [21S01] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)')
```

I know there is a way to do this with procedures but I want to avoid using procedures, unless it actually is the logically better solution.

First I thought it was due to a wrong time format so I replaced them with NULL for now.

Comment: There are six columns shown in the screenshot of your table. What makes you think SQL Server will automatically shred a single JSON value and spread it across those six columns?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I thought to have read that since the key names match the column names it would automatically map it. Is that not the case?

Comment: That is not the case. You can either deserialize the JSON in Python and send the six values as query parameters, or you can use [`OPENJSON()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql) in T-SQL to deserialize the JSON and insert the six values from that.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server will not "map" columns for you automatically. You need to use `OPENJSON` or `JSON_VALUE` to get the data.

```sql
INSERT INTO SQLTable
  (id, created_at, creator_id, updated_at, updater_id, name)
SELECT
FROM OPENJSON(?)
  WITH (
    id uniqueidentifier,
    created_at datetime,
    creator_id varchar(30),
    updated_at datetime,
    updater_id varchar(30),
    name varchar(100)
  ) AS j;
```

Alternatively you can read the values in Python and pass through separate parameters.